# How to append something between a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="x">
  <tr>
    <td class='col1'>
      Hello <span class='name'></span> How are u ?
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
var variable = $('table#x').find(".col1").html().find("span.name").append(' Jack..!').replace('u', 'you');
alert(variable);
```

Now, I want this output:

```
<td class='col1'>Hello <span class='name'>Jack..!</span> How are you ?<td>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/7edvm141/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212002/how-to-append-something-between-a-javascript-string?noredirect=1#comment56168406_34212002), you could use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3nnvqjs/)

```
$('table#x .col1 span.name').append(' Jack..!').parent().text(function () {
  return $(this).text().replace('u', 'you');
});
```

There were a couple issues in your code. For one, you can't chain `.append()` after the `.html()` method. In addition, the `.replace()` method wasn't changing the text. To fix this, you could pass an anonymous function to the `.text()` method and return the replaced text.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but how can I do that as sibling instead of into-element *(`append()`)*? I mean is something like this `... Hello <span class='name'></span>Jack..! How ...`

Answer (score 4):

You already have a class you can target, 'name'. You can simply add the text to this:

```
$('.name').text('Jack..!')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j7rxwyj/